# Efeito estilo rolagem do aplicativo do Instagram

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de usar o efeito de "rolagem" que o instagram usa no seu aplicativo, alternando para a câmera e para a time-line. Porém não sei o nome desse efeito, poderiam me dizer qual é, ou dar exemplos de sites que mostrem um tutorial do mesmo?

Comment: No app ou na web?

Comment: Igual o que eles usam no aplicativo Guilherme.

Comment: Você poderia gravar um video exemplificando o efeito?

Comment: Tem algum vídeo? É aquele mesmo do snapchat? Em que vc alterna de telas deslizando pro lado?

Comment: É esse mesmo que tu falou Stéfano.

Comment: Só me diz mais uma coisa. Tu quer que a rolagem aconteça quando aperta um botão ou quando arrasta com o dedo?

Comment: Acredito que esse efeito se chama "Slide Tabs" https://youtu.be/23vE3VUke5o?t=19m55s

Comment: Pronto, respondi a sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu editei e adicionei o efeito de arraste.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, você pode utilizar o **jQuery Mobile 1.4.5**.

Você encontra ele neste link:

```
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/
```

Primeiro, com o modo **tabs**:

```
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/tabs/
```

Mais o efeito **slide**:

```
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/transitions/
```

Para efeito de **arraste**, utilize o **HammerJS**:

```
http://hammerjs.github.io/
```

Utilizando os dois você deixa igualzinho a do celular.